# Instanced GLSL shaders in Vulkan?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

This is the (simplest) instancing shader I can come up with, which basically just transforms a bunch of 2D primitives:

```
#version 400
#extension GL_ARB_draw_instanced : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform VConstants {
    vec4 vfuniforms[48];
};
in vec4 pos;
void main() {

    gl_Position = vec4(0.0,0,0.0,1);
    gl_Position.x = dot(pos, vfuniforms[int(float(gl_InstanceID) * 2.0)]);
    gl_Position.y = dot(pos, vfuniforms[int(float(gl_InstanceID) * 2.0 + 1.0)]);

}
```

If I try to compile this to SPIR-V with the glslangValidator that comes with the Vulkan SDK, I get:

```
WARNING: 0:2: '#extension' : extension not supported: GL_ARB_draw_instanced
ERROR: 0:14: 'gl_InstanceID' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 1 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

If I remove the `#extension GL_ARB_draw_instanced` line, I still get the `gl_InstanceID` error. Is it possible to write instancing GLSL and compile them to SPIR-V? If so, what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The form of GLSL that the reference compiler uses to generate SPIR-V for Vulkan doesn't use normal OpenGL extensions. It follows the rules of GLSL 4.50, but it amends/overrides them by the dictates of the implicit pseudo-extension [GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/misc/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt). Note that you don't use #extension to initiate it; it is *assumed* to be active because you're using the Vulkan GLSL-to-SPIR-V compiler.

In particular, this extension *removes* `gl_InstanceID` (and `gl_VertexID`). Instead, it creates its own variable, `gl_InstanceIndex`. The reason for this is because OpenGL was... stupid.

See, `gl_InstanceID` is the instance starting from the first instance in the [instanced drawing command](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing). However, when base-instanced rendering was added (the ability to render an arbitrary range of instances), `gl_InstanceID` was not updated to match. So if you start from a base instance of 2 with 5 instances, the first `gl_InstanceID` will *still be zero* (followed by 1, 2, 3, and 4). So the only things the base instance affects are [instanced arrays](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Instanced_Array).

Naturally, Vulkan wanted no part of OpenGL's stupidity in this regard, so it uses what most people would expect the instance value to be: the actual instance index the user asked to render. But this required a new variable, so that users wouldn't do what you're attempting: to accidentally use the same variable across both OpenGL and Vulkan without realizing that they have different semantics.

You'll either need two shaders or to check if `VULKAN` is defined, which is will be for those using the GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl extension. If it is, you use `gl_InstanceIndex`; if not, you use `gl_InstanceID`. Also, your #extension declarations should be scoped as well, since the Vulkan GLSL-to-SPIR-V compiler will assume GLSL 4.50, and it won't necessarily offer up extensions.

Comment: I still apparently need the `#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable` or else I get compile errors with `layout(binding = ...)`. The docs for GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl use layout bindings, but don't seem to mention this). Anyhow, my instanced shaders now compile - so thanks.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito: Perhaps it's confused by your `#version 400` declaration. They really should have had their own version number: `#version 100 vulkan`, the way that GLSL ES has `#version 300 es`.

Answer (score 3):

The GL_ARB_draw_instanced extension is not necessary, it is supported by core GLSL 1.40 and vulkan. glslang does not seem to use the extension anyway: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/blob/master/glslang/MachineIndependent/Initialize.cpp#L1707

Instead of gl_InstanceID, I think that gl_InstanceIndex has to be used. The difference is that gl_InstanceID counts from 0, where gl_InstanceIndex counts from the base instance. See

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#interfaces-builtin-variables

for more information about the builtins.